# How to add an event listener in one file for an emitter in a different file using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm new to this javascript thing, so I'm sure this is an easy question.

The file structure looks like this:

```
/app.js
/app/controller/users.controller.js
/app/routes/socketio.js
```

I'd like to have an emit function that fires when a specific controller is called in users.js, and a listener in the socketio.js file that picks it up. The purpose for this is so that when the controller calls a function that updates the database, I want it to push the results to socketio, which is already connected to a dashboard.

I know how to create an emit/listener event when they're in the same file, but I have no idea how to get them to talk between files/directories.

Thanks in advance!

---

UPDATE:
Here is what the code looks like (i've simplified it a bunch to get rid of the unnecessary information):

```
// /app.js

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

var debug = require('debug')('nodemit:server');
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var socket = require('./routes/socketio')(io);

var port = 3000;

server.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Server is listening on port: ' + port);
});
```

users.controller.js

```
// /app/controllers/users.controller.js

exports.getUsers = function(req, res){

    var user = req.params.user;

    // I would to be able to emit something from here....

    res.json(user);
}
```

socketio.js

```
// /app/routes/socketio.js

module.exports = function(io){

    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

        //... and have an event listener here that picks up when it is hit

    });

}
```

Comment: Have you tried passing your `io` or `socket` object as an argument to a function in `users.js`?

Comment: like i said, i'm new to this stuff so I honestly don't even know what that means. I'm sure this is easy, i just don't know how to do it...

Comment: I'm not sure I can answer your question without seeing code, but basically: you want to call `socket.emit`, but you don't have `socket`. The solution is: whenever you *do* have `socket`, pass it into a function from the `users.js` file.

Comment: Right on the socketio homepage there's a little example: http://socket.io/

Comment: @apsillers ok, let i'll try and distill out the code that is applicable here, and update it in a minute